# How to display content from database on webpage and allow the user to select for more information

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

Firstly, a quick apology if something similar has been asked. I have done my level best to find a previously posted solution but as my knowledge of web development is somewhat basic, I may be struggling to explain the issue correctly.

As I feel the need to do a lot of explaining below to try and be clear about exactly what it is I am trying to do, it may be more useful to actually see the site to try and understand how it functions and what I am explaining in order to understand fully what I am attempting to do. It is available on 000freewebhost at present so just follow the link below:

https://legal-bytes.000webhostapp.com/topics.php

TL;DR I am selecting records from a database table, storing them in an array and then displaying each one as an individual hyperlink to another page which will contain more information depending on which link has been selected. 
How do I establish which link has been selected, insofar as I can then query the database once more to select the additional information I want to display?

Now, on to the problem. (Please note, I will post my code below my explanation.)

For a university project, I am designing a website containing information about UK law. Part of this website contains a list of topics of law. Users can click on any topic and be brought to a new page where they can select the type of material they are looking for. Following this they will be brought to another page where they can select the specific resource they want.

A quick example should clarify this: A user navigates to the 'Topics' page and selects 'Company Law' from the topics available. They can then choose from 'Articles', 'Books', 'Cases' or 'Legislation' (all relevant to Company Law)(These 4 options are what I will refer to collectively as 'resource types'). So they choose 'Cases'. The next page they will see is a list of all the cases available on the site for Company Law (these are the 'resources' themselves). The final step would be to select the case they want more information on and they would have this displayed on a new page.

The way I have designed the site so far is by using a database to store the information about these resources. For instance, regarding a case, I would store the name of the case and the facts of that case. To display the resources, I am querying the database and selecting all those records from the relevant table which are of the same topic type (company law, land law etc.) and of the same resource type (case, article etc.). This records are stored in an array and the page is finally populated with these records using a 'FOR' loop. The records are displayed on the page then as links which have been created dynamically using the loop mentioned above.

**All of the above is working as intended - the following is where my problem is:**

The idea is that when a user selects on of these links (these resources) they will be taken to a new page which will display the information (say the facts of a case in the above example). However, I am unable to figure out how to check which link (resource) the user has clicked on to be able to display the correct information on the following page.

**Below is the code from the pages in question:**
Here is the 'FOR' loop mentioned:

```
    <?php for ($x=0; $x < count($resource_info); $x++): ?>
    <a href="info-page.php?<?php echo $pageref ?>&<?php echo $pagetype ?>&<?php echo $resource_info[$x] ?>">
        <div class="topic-group">
            <div class="cases">  
                <p><?php echo $resource_info[$x] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>  
<?php endfor ?>
```

Just a quick explanation of the above:
The $resource_info variable is my array which stores the records selected from the database.
$pageref is a variable I am using to determine what topic is selected (e.g. 'company' would be the $pageref referring to 'Company Law') 
$pagetype is another variable which refers to what type of resource is being displayed (e.g. 'cases' would be the $pagetype referring to 'Cases')

As was mentioned above, I am querying the database to select the relevant records. The code for this can be seen below. You will notice that topic_id is set to 4 and type_id is set to 1 - there is a reason for this which is unrelated to the present issue however suffice to say the sql is set to search for any Cases (type_id) relating to Company law (topic_id).

include('topic-info.php');
$resource_info = array();

```
if ($searchdb == true) {

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM resource_info WHERE topic_id= '4' AND type_id= '1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $x = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($resource_info, ($row['title']));
        }
    } 
    $conn->close();
```

A further explanation of the above:
The topic-info.php is another file which is used for defining the values of the variables which I explained above.
You will notice that it checks if the $searchdb boolean is set to true. This is established in the topic-info.php file (see below).
This code also shows just how the $resource_info array is being populated, in this case we see it storing the data in the 'title' field of the records found - this is simply the names of any cases it finds in this scenario.

Finally then, this is the code from the topic-info.php file relevant to explaining the definition of various variables above:

```
if (isset($_GET['cases'])) {
    $pagetype = "cases";
}
```

/* ------ irrelevant code ommitted --------- */

```
if (isset($_GET['company'])) {
    $pagetitle = "Company Law";
    $pageref = "company";
    if (isset($_GET['cases'])) {
        $typeref = "case";
        $searchdb = true;
    }
}
```

Explanation of above:
Here is how the $pagetype and $pageref variables are defined, based on the links the user has chosen so far. It also sets the $searchdb boolean to true when the condition is met - this condition WILL be met when the user clicks on 'Company Law' and 'Cases'.

I do apologise for the ramble but I am still fairly new to a project of this size and feel I may be way out of my depth with what I am attempting to do. Thus I am not sure how much I need to include to explain the issue. On the other hand I wonder if it would be as simple as using an onclick event to set a variable - or would this require something more complicated such as Javascript or AJAX?

Please do understand that the vast majority of this is working however it is only the final part I cannot figure out - how do I establish which record I need to select from the table?

Many thanks.

Comment: "How do I establish which link has been selected," by adding a parameter to the link which contains the ID of the item being selected. e.g. `www.example.com/somescript.php?id=2` . Then somescript.php looks for `$_GET["id"]` to read that value coming in, and uses it to select the right data. You appear to have grasped that point, so what's the issue? Your question is massive and it's a bit hard to see the wood for the trees. Where precisely are you failing? I think maybe you're not getting the value in the GET and using it in the SQL query...is that what you don't understand?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the reply, feeling a little silly now - your suggestion is the solution to my problem. It's so simple but it had just never occurred to me to do that until you mentioned it. If you read through that whole ramble above, apologies as I was (very clearly now) over complicating the matters. Nevertheless thanks for your assistance today! :)

What I was failing to understand was that something as simple as $_GET['id'] would return the value I required - I was so used to having definite values to look for ('company', 'cases' etc) simply treating as a variable just never occurred

Answer (score 0):

I perfer to go with foreach loop that will deferentially give you result what you are looking for.

```
<?php
foreach (array(1, 2, 3, 4) as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php